# How to center the pagination in jQuery Bootstrap DataTables plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, datatables

I am using jQuery's DataTables plugin with Bootstrap 3.1 for sorting & paginating server side contents.

This is how my table looks like

http://datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap-simple.html

Pagination & Sorting works fine...But by default pagination is on right side of the table. I want to show it on the center of the table. My knowledge in CSS is minimal, so I am not sure where to make changes. How to acheive this?

Comment: you cant align exactly center for that pagination part only. Because the pagination message "Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries" and pagination dividing the width 50% each. But you can align it in left side. it means after 50% it will start.

Comment: I did that by adding div.dataTables_paginate {
                float: inherit;
                margin: 0;              
            } @Suresh Ponnukalai

Comment: But by default....datatables is dividing the div's into col-xs-6. Can i change that to col-xs-4 & col-xs-8 manually? @Suresh Ponnukalai

Comment: If it is a fixed content, we can play with margin left minus valuse. But as you said, it is a dynamic content.

Comment: i think you can't. It is being used in other places also.

Comment: What if I don't want "Showing 1 to 10 of 57 entries" this div?? How to remove it?? @Suresh Ponnukalai

Comment: you can remove it using .dataTables_info{display:none} But it will remove only text not the area.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Initialize your DataTable as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    /* DataTables */
    var myTable = $("#myTable").dataTable({
        "sDom": '<"row view-filter"<"col-sm-12"<"pull-left"l><"pull-right"f><"clearfix">>>t<"row view-pager"<"col-sm-12"<"text-center"ip>>>'
    });

});
```

Comment: This centers "Showing 1 to 10 of 379 entries" not my pagination div. ANd my default font size also changed. @Khalid T.

Comment: Now that you have full control over the DataTable DOM, you can modify your CSS overrides as needed. For example, try this: div.dataTables_info { position: absolute; } div.dataTables_paginate { float: none; }

Answer (score 11):

None of the solutions mentioned here so far worked for me.

This is what I use:

```
 div.dataTables_paginate {text-align: center}
```

The `div` with the class `dataTables_paginate`, in my layout, has a width equal to 100% of its containing div. The `text-align` is centering the `ul` control - `<ul class="pagination">` contained within `dataTables_paginate`.

My `"DOM"` attribute is very simple. It looks like this:

```
 "dom": 'rtp'
```

Comment: What is the "r" for? I get "Table"/"Paginate"

Comment: pRocess display element - from [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)

Answer (score 5):

This is based on Karl's answer, but with DataTables v1.10.12 I had to provide a few extra details in my CSS override file in order to get them to stick.

```
div.dataTables_info {position:absolute}
div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_paginate {float:none; text-align:center}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the following to get pagination in the center of the table:

```
$('table').DataTable({
   "dom": '<"row"<"col-sm-4"l><"col-sm-4 text-center"p><"col-sm-4"f>>tip'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me (bootstrap 4):

```
.dataTables_paginate {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want all pagination to be centered. Here's the workaround.

**CSS**

```
<style>
        .dt-center .pagination {
            justify-content: center !important;
        }
</style>
```

**DataTable**

```
<"dt-center"p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4">
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-8">
         <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="example_paginate">
         </div
   </div>
</div>
```

and remove the property of `float:right;` from class

> dataTables_paginate

Answer (score 0):

If you are only concerned about placing the pagination in the middle of the dataTable (underneath or above), the following code should do it:

```
.dataTables_paginate {
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: right;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<style>
.pagination{
    display: inline-flex;
}
div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_paginate{
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

what i did is :
style.css line 2731

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
width: 50px; //def:35px;
height: 30px; //def:35px;
border-radius: 10%; //def:50%;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
vertical-align: top;
color: #7E7E7E!important;
margin: 0 2px;
border: 0!important;
line-height: 17px; //def:21px;
box-shadow: none!important; }
```

the number will center at middle

Comment: sorry, actually this only make the pagination number at center box it self.. not make the whole pagination area at center.. my mistake.. again sorry..